# LibGdx RAM usage continuously increases

Tags: java, libgdx, ram

I wrote these 3 classes to test them on android. If I just press Menu button and hide the app, then open it again, then hide and reopen it again and again ram usage increases every time I hide the app.

The same problem occurs if I just switch between classes inside the app, app uses more and more ram.

I was looking for a solution of this problem here and I saw tutorials on yotube, but I have not found it. I don't understand what can be wrong here.

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

```java
public class MyEF extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create() {

        setScreen(new TestScreen1(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        super.resume();
    }

}

// TEST1
public class TestScreen1 implements Screen {

    private MyEF game;

    public TestScreen1(MyEF game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
            game.setScreen(new TestScreen2(game));
            dispose();
            System.out.println("TOUCHED ");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        game.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }
    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }
    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }
}

// TEST2
public class TestScreen2 implements Screen {

    private MyEF game;

    public TestScreen2(MyEF game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
            game.setScreen(new TestScreen1(game));
            dispose();
            System.out.println("TOUCHED ");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        game.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }
    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }
    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time the user presses, you create a new Screen. That uses memory
You should have a static instance of each screen instead of creating a new one each time the player presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not have any static `Screens` because of this. "Resetting" screens will introduce bugs and not very well maintainable code. It is easier in many cases to just create a new "clean" screen.

Also you are describing an *effect* here. Not a *problem*. Yes the memory usage increases. But is it a problem? No! Why not? Because the user won't send the app to the background and restart it 1000 times in a row. And even if he does, the memory usage will not grow endlessly. It keeps growing because the amount of memory which gets added is so small that the JVM does not even invoke the garbage collector.

After enough iterations of resuming the app, the garbage collector will eventually kick in and clean up all your unused screens.

In general you should not change your architecture now, based on this behaviour. As a rule of thumb you can always instantiate new objects, for example when switching screens, or when doing things only once. The user will not be bothered if the garbage collector kicks in in a loading screen, or when the game just started. You should only be concerned when doing it in the `render()` method, because then the garbage collector might clean up while the actual gameplay and may cause lags.

Comment: I compared with other apps and games for android. Amount of RAM remains unchanged. I thought I was doing something wrong.
I wrote a little game. If I start it, RAM amount equals ~11bm. If I just switch between screens ram amount increases contineously, so I had ~200mb of ram used. I think it's not ok

Comment: You are right, that seems too much. Is this really your whole code? I cannot see where that much memory is allocated. Are you loading any assets somewhere maybe and do not dispose them, like textures for example?

Comment: This code is example, I wrote it because I wanted to find my mistakes. And yes, I dispose everithing that is possible, like here in example: setScreen(); , then dispose();. I do it not in render method, but in buttons

Comment: So this isn't the actual code that you run to get the 200MB memory usage?

Comment: no, but I really asked about this code, because I have the same problem(If I tap on the screen continuously ram amount increases) and there is nothing yet. I try to do it like it shown on libgdx page, why it happens, I don't understand

Comment: In this case it is because the gargabe collector didn't do anything yet. Try to add a call to `System.gc()` after you `setScreen(new ...)` and see if it still has this effect. It shouldn't. In your real application there are other resources somewhere which you do not dispose. But without showing that code, I can't help you.

Comment: System.gc() is very helpful. I just cheсked it, but ram still increases sometime, about 0,01mb. I think it's the best answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stuntmania is correct. Creating new objects = increased RAM usage, *especially* when you do it during the `render()` method. In game development in general, and LibGDX in particular, you should always question your usage of the **new** keyword. Make things static wherever possible.

Specifically, your main game class should do something like this:

```
public class MyEF extends Game {
    public static TestScreen1 myScreen1;
    public static TestScreen2 myScreen2;

    @Override
    public static void create() {
        myScreen1 = new TestScreen1(this);
        myScreen2 = new TestScreen2(this);
        setScreen(myScreen1);
    }

    (...)
}
```

Then, in your `render()` method for each of the screens, you would simply call `game.setScreen(myScreen2)`. This way, you are no longer creating new objects during each render cycle.

Comment: Having static Screens is not a good idea in general and it solves a not-existing problem. "Make things static wherever possible". No! -1

Comment: thanks, but I have only more problems bacause of static